# mysql select - if no matches for given option, match a different option

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find users in a table by their ID number. A few users don't have an ID number, so for them I want to find by birthdate. So I want a select statement that does this:

Pseudo-code:

```
SELECT user FROM users WHERE id = idnumber
      if that is not found, then
                     WHERE dob = dob
```

I don't want to match date of birth if there is a match for id, because that will return too many results. I can do this in two separate selects, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

I am using PHP with PDO

Comment: What happens when you have multiple rows with the same birthdate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user FROM users
WHERE id = :idnumber
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT user FROM users WHERE id = :idnumber)
    AND dob = :dob)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer man. Looks nice. Haven't used `EXISTS` in this case. :)

Comment: Ah, this looks nice! x)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `OR` and prioritization.  Assuming you want only one row back:

```
SELECT u.user
FROM users u
WHERE u.id = $idnumber or u.dob = $dob
ORDER BY (u.id = $idnumber) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, if you want multiple rows back, then a variation on Barmar's solution might optimize better:

```
SELECT u.user
FROM users u
WHERE u.id = :idnumber
UNION ALL
SELECT u.user
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.id = $idnumber) AND
      dob = $dob;
```

MySQL can be finicky about using indexes for `OR` conditions.  This version will definitely use indexes on `users(id)` and `users(dob)`.